# Use of Binomial Theorem in IP address distribution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distribution, binomial-cdf, binomial-theorem

I am currently making a project on Binomial theorem/Distribution for my semester. I need some very interesting real life applications of these to add in my project(I need to add in depth explanation of that application). I came accross these applications:

1. Distribution of Internet Protocol Address (or IP Address)
   This method in IP distribution condition where you have been given IP address of the fixed host and number of host are more
   than total round off then you may use this theorem to distribute bits so that all host may be covered in IP addressing. This
   method is known as variable sub netting.
2. Weather forecasting
   Moreover binomial theorem is used in forecast services. The
   disaster forecast also depends upon the use of binomial
   theorems

But I couldn't find the explanation for point 1 anywhere. I know this is somewhat lame but if any of u can explain it in detail or if u could simply explain some other real life application of Binomial theorem/Distribution to me, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: This doesn't sound quite like a programming question. Regardless - try asking the author of this text what exactly they meant.

Comment: I know! But still this is based on computer networks and I really need help in this otherwise I wouldn't have asked here. Hope you all will understand!